# Dataset created with Apache Drill+MongoDB does not include columns where values are null or empty arrays

Tags: mongodb, apache-superset, apache-drill

I have connected Apache Superset to MongoDB through Apache Drill. When querying in Apache Drill Web UI, all data is shown correctly.
Im trying create a dataset with a schema in MongoDB, but it creates without some columns. After some investigating, I figured out that it reads all columns from the first document (it is shown first in MongoDB Compass) where values are not null and arrays are not empty. Other columns are ignored and to put into dataset

I found that apache drill has session options like store.json.all_text_mode and store.mongo.all_text_mode which reads all data as varchar.
I just don't know how to set these options for apache superset session.
Or is there something else I can do?
Any help is appreciated.